# printing megamenu in inner pages [Magento]

Tags: magento

I have two megamenus in the site, the top header megamenu and in the sidebar. I'm struggling to print homepage sidebar megamenu in inner pages(like in Category page and subcategory page)

To print sidebar megamenu in home page - 2columns-left.phtml

*Backend : pages > Homepage > design > xml layout*

```
<reference name="megamenu_left">
 <block type="megamenu/list" name="megamenu.list2.theme" as="megaMenuLeft2" template="sm/megamenu/megamenu-left.phtml">
    <action method="setConfig">
        <values>  
            <group_id>3</group_id>
            <theme>2</theme>
        </values>
    </action>
 </block>
</reference>
```

*mytheme > template > layout : page.xml*

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="megamenu_left" as="megamenu_left" translate="label">
      <label>Left Megamenu</label>
</block>
```

and finally in *mytheme> template > page > 2columns-left.phtml(homepage)*

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('megamenu_left') ?>
```

From three part above, the megamenu-left is printed in homepage.

Now to print the same block in category listing page, I have added this block below inside a left reference in *layout > catalog.xml*  and it automatically prints the menu.

```
<block type="megamenu/list" name="megamenu.list2.theme" as="megaMenuLeft2" template="sm/megamenu/megamenu-left.phtml">
<action method="setConfig">
    <values>  
        <group_id>3</group_id>
        <theme>2</theme>
    </values>
</action>
</block>
```

The problem is I want to make as accordion with more other megamenus so i need to print it in control, like printing from **getChildHtml('megamenu_left')**